# tsql code to sync two xml documents

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

**xml 1**

```
<Team>
  <Players>
    <Player id="1" timestamp="11/03/2012 08:10:12">30</Player>
    <Player id="2" timestamp="11/02/2012 09:11:12">40</Player>
  <Players>
</Team>
```

**xml 2**

```
<Team>
  <Players>
    <Player id="1" timestamp="11/02/2012 09:10:12">10</Player>
    <Player id="2" timestamp="11/03/2012 10:11:12">20</Player>
    <Player id="3" timestamp="11/03/2012 13:00:00">50</Player>
  <Players>
</Team>
```

OUTPUT when we merge the above two XMLs based on timestamp element:

```
<Team>
  <Players>
    <Player id="1" timestamp="11/02/2012 09:10:12">30</Player>
    <Player id="2" timestamp="11/03/2012 10:11:12">20</Player>
    <Player id="3" timestamp="11/03/2012 13:00:00">50</Player>
  <Players>
</Team>
```

Could anyone please help me with T-SQL code to do this in SQL Server 2005/2008

Comment: @marc_s - Looks like the later one for an `id` overwrites any earlier one.

Answer (score 2):

Using this approach with two nested CTE's, you can get close - but not all the way:

```
DECLARE @XML1 XML = '<Team>
  <Players>
    <Player id="1" timestamp="11/03/2012 08:10:12">30</Player>
    <Player id="2" timestamp="11/02/2012 09:11:12">40</Player>
  </Players>
</Team>'

DECLARE @XML2 XML = '<Team>
  <Players>
    <Player id="1" timestamp="11/02/2012 09:10:12">10</Player>
    <Player id="2" timestamp="11/03/2012 10:11:12">20</Player>
    <Player id="3" timestamp="11/03/2012 13:00:00">50</Player>
  </Players>
</Team>'

-- extract the ID, Timestamp and node values from both XML variables 
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
    ID = P1.value('@id', 'int'),
    TS = P1.value('@timestamp', 'datetime2'),
    NodeValue = P1.value('(.)[1]', 'int')
FROM @XML1.nodes('/Team/Players/Player') AS XTbl1(P1)

UNION 

SELECT
    ID = P2.value('@id', 'int'),
    TS = P2.value('@timestamp', 'datetime2'),
    NodeValue = P2.value('(.)[1]', 'int')
FROM @XML2.nodes('/Team/Players/Player') AS XTbl2(P2)
),
-- partition and sequentially number the result, so that the newest 
-- (most recent) item can be extracted
CTE2 AS   
(
    SELECT ID, TS, NodeValue,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TS DESC)
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT 
    ID AS '@id',
    TS AS '@timestamp',
    NodeValue AS 'text()'
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNum = 1
FOR XML PATH('Player'), ROOT('Players')
```

Results in output like this:

```
<Players>
  <Player id="1" timestamp="2012-11-03T08:10:12">30</Player>
  <Player id="2" timestamp="2012-11-03T10:11:12">20</Player>
  <Player id="3" timestamp="2012-11-03T13:00:00">50</Player>
</Players>
```

Comment: thk you for the solution. I will try and let you know the results.

Comment: hi marc, if I use id='football' in input xml the o/p xml show id='f' only one alphabet. and for timestamp in o/p xml there is extra letter 't'. could you please help me with this.